# Update custom field from other custom data

Tags: api, activities, hooks, relationships

I'm trying to use a php hook to automatically create a relationship between two contacts. Let me set the stage for you.

Meeting Extender: a custom data set that extends the meeting activity(activity entity). It basically records a few custom fields, two of which are contact references(think pitcher and pitchee). These two fields would be two integers referring to contact A and contact B. Basically, I want to write a hook that creates a relationship, called Pitched to (A to B) and been Pitched(B to A).

The pipeline

A meeting is created, in the custom field set Google is saved as contact A and Apple is saved as contact B. The hook should realize a new activity has been created, check if the Pitched relationship exists between Google --> Apple and if not create it.

This was my attempt so far(in an extension)

```
function checkActivityMakeRelationship_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
/* This file checks if an activity was created and if so
 */

    if(($op == 'create' || $op == 'edit') && $objectName == 'Activity') {
        $result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'create', array(
        'sequential' => 1,
        'contact_id_a' => **integer-referring-to-contact-a**,
        'contact_id_b' => **integer-referring-to-contact-b**,
        'relationship_type_id' => 11,//this is the relationship type for pitched
    ));
    }
}
```

Ignoring the 'relationship-already-exists' check for now, how to I find the correct integers for the contact A and contact B i just entered in to my custom data set. I imagine it is a part of $op but I'm not sure how to access it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.
V

PS: I'm running wordpress 4.2.4 and civicrm 4.6.6

Comment: I'm assuming its something such as $objectRef['custom_x'] or $object->custom_x where x is the proper integer but neither of these is working.

Answer (score 1):

SO I was able to figure this out, turns out I wasn't able to reference the custom data directly from the activity object but had to use the api to grab the custom data related to that activity object.

```
function checkActivityMakeRelationship_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
/* This function checks if a specific activity was created and if so makes a related relationship
*/

if(($op == 'create' || $op == 'edit') && $objectName == 'Activity') {
    $params = array(
        'sequential' => 1,
        'id' => $objectId,
        'return' => "custom_50,custom_51",//replace with your specific custom
    );
    $activity = civicrm_api3('Activity', 'get', $params);
    $contact_a_id = (int)$activity[values][0]['custom_50_id'];//note the appended _id
    $contact_b_id = (int)$activity[values][0]['custom_51_id'];// appended _id
    $result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'create', array(
    'sequential' => 1,
    'contact_id_a' => $contact_a_id,
    'contact_id_b' => $contact_b_id,
    'relationship_type_id' => 11,//your specific relationship id
    ));
}
```

}