# after i use api to update the database results not immediately showing

Tags: api, relationships, database

I'm running into an issue with the api. I use the following call to write to the relationships datatable

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'create', array(
    'sequential' => 1,
    'contact_id_a' => $contact_a_id,
    'contact_id_b' => $contact_b_id,
    'relationship_type_id' => 11,//your specific relationship id
));
```

from my solution in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4619/765

However, when I then go to the relationship tab the new entry is not immediately visible. I usually have to force a refresh by changing the relationships per page from 10 to 25 and then the new entry appears. How can I bypass/avoid this problem?

Thanks,
V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have to 'force' the summary page to rebuild. You can do this by re-building your userContext (which will be the summary page):

```
$session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton;
CRM_Utils_System::redirect($session->readUserContext());
```